# what will happen when a NFS sharing directory cannot be loaded remotely?

Tags: debian, nfs

If a NFS server network fails, the client will have a problem to load a shared NFS directory from the server. In this case, if a local directory does exist, will the client visit the local directory automatically instead? or the directory will just become unavailable?

Comment: Please edit question to define fail.

Comment: ok. is it better now?

Comment: define “loaded remotely”. Are you saying that it can not be mounted, or that it was mounted but then the network is disconnected, or something else?

Comment: I am interested in both: 1) cannot be mounted due to network 2) it was mounted but then lost the connection (for example the server is down after mounted).

Comment: Nothing else will ever happen if you can't even mount the NFS(mount syscall fail, nothing would change). It seems that you didn't do too much thinking before you ask.

Comment: so in case of NFS server is not available, a visit from the client machine to the directory will fail. It will not visit the existing local directory, right?

Comment: Please add clarifications to question.

Comment: Please read up about the *soft/hard* and *fg/bg* mount options in the [NFS man page](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/nfs-common/nfs.5.en.html) and clarify your question in the light of that.